# 2010-Date.aspx modification

Tags: 2010, blog

I'm trying to adjust some of the xsl code for articles that appear under the archives area on a 2010 blog we've created.

I have a new column that will display an alternate "author" but I cannot seem to find where to edit the xsl to add in my new column to appear. I can't use sample data in SPD as the date.aspx page doesn't show any..

I thought to create an alternate blog.xsl page, point to that, and edit the xsl file which date.aspx points to.. but no go, nothing changes.

Can anyone point me to the appropriate file to make these sort of adjustments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the xml isn't written to the .aspx pages, instead referencing the default SharePoint templates. You can force SharePoint Designer to make explicit code for your column by making a small change in the Design view. Try adding a letter next to the displayed value, or changing the tag properties. If this alternate author column exists only in xml, the simplest way might be to add another column to your dataview as a throwaway and then replace its `$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name` with your custom xml. Also of note: you will not be able to reference any fields that aren't part of your dataview, so you may need to add columns then delete the text portion of their headers and cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto this, in case anybody has the same issue—having to change the blog post author name within an organization—I have come across an article (from the ever so informative Marc Anderson) that details the XSL changes necessary to implement a new author name.

http://sympmarc.com/2012/04/04/customizing-the-display-of-a-sharepoint-2010-blog/#viewSource